# How to bring a Truecaller like pop up at a particular time of day like an alarm using flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, android-background

I tired to solve this by using **android_alarm_manager_plus** to schedule the background event at a particular time. And moreover till now that worked fine, but to show the truecaller like pop-up I used the package **system_alert_window** from pub.dev to show the pop up.
As long as the app is open in the background the pop-up works and it displays as an overlay. But when the alarm event triggers when the app is closed, it pops up you app has crashed

So summing up : The **system_alert_window** when called as long as the app is open, it works. But when called when app is closed, it crashes.

Please someone help me with a solution or a way around this.

Android version used to test 11 & 12

Crash Logs :-

```
01-10 01:07:54.195 3397 3397 E AndroidRuntime: at dev.fluttercommunity.plus.androidalarmmanager.AlarmService.onCreate(AlarmService.java:351) 
01-10 01:07:54.195 3397 3397 E AndroidRuntime: at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:4307) 
01-10 01:07:54.195 3397 3397 E AndroidRuntime: ... 8 more 
01-10 01:07:54.201 2225 3489 I DropBoxManagerService: add tag=data_app_crash isTagEnabled=true flags=0x2 01-10 
01:07:54.211 2225 2324 W BroadcastQueue: Background execution not allowed: receiving Intent { act=android.intent.action.DROPBOX_ENTRY_ADDED flg=0x10 (has extras) } to com.google.android.gms/.stats.service.DropBoxEntryAddedReceiver 
01-10 01:07:54.212 2225 2324 W BroadcastQueue: Background execution not allowed: receiving Intent { act=android.intent.action.DROPBOX_ENTRY_ADDED flg=0x10 (has extras) } to com.google.android.gms/.chimera.GmsIntentOperationService$PersistentTrustedReceiver
```

Comment: Can you post the crash logs?

Comment: I have added the crashlogs from logcat